# Access private members in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, private-members, busyindicator

I am pretty new to Silverlight but I see this being done all the time. I just don't know yet how to do it.

How do I access functionality of a private member?

First of all, I got a runtime error when trying to use the Busy Window Indicator when a seperate thread called the window code associated with the BusyIndicator.

Anyway, so my solution was to try to make this call as public as possible.  But now I am getting a compile error.  Can someone help me with this?

Please suggest how I can get past this error message.

[image: IMG]http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/Image57.png[/IMG]

Answer (score 5):

It's not a private member issue - `BusyWindow` is an *instance* member, i.e. associated with an *instance* of the containing class. Your `setbusywindow` property is a *static* member, i.e. associated with the type itself. If there are multiple instances of your class (or none) which instance would you expect to fetch the `BusyWindow` property from?

You need to learn about the [`static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) keyword and its meaning in various contexts.

Note that currently your `BusyWindow` field is public, which is generally a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work the way you've done it, either `BusyWindow` needs instantiating or `IsBusy` needs to be made static.

```
public static bool IsBusy{get;set;}
```

This is because you're trying to access an instance member asif it's a static member.